# How to group/sum xts time series by whole seconds

Tags: r, time-series, aggregate, xts

Any package can do the following example? I have big `xts` dataset in millisecond level.
Can I sum the `coredata` up to second level?
The time is index.

For example:

[image]

The ideal result is:

[image]

Comment: Please make your example reproducible by including data we can copy and paste into R. Try using the `dput(data)` function and pasting in the output rather than images of dataframes

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate by using `aggregate.zoo()` from the `zoo` package.

```
library(xts)
library(zoo)

# A simple example time series
xx <- xts(1:20, as.POSIXct((1:20)/5, origin="2000-01-01"))

aggregate(xx, as.POSIXct(trunc(time(xx), "sec")), sum)

# 2000-01-01 01:00:00 10
# 2000-01-01 01:00:01 35
# 2000-01-01 01:00:02 60
# 2000-01-01 01:00:03 85
# 2000-01-01 01:00:04 20
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(xts)

# To see subsecond timestamp values:
options(digits.secs = 3)

set.seed(1)
x <- xts(rnorm(10), as.POSIXct("2018-11-01 00:00:00.3") + seq(0.05, 3, length.out = 10))
# [,1]
# 2018-11-01 00:00:00.349 -0.6264538
# 2018-11-01 00:00:00.677  0.1836433
# 2018-11-01 00:00:01.005 -0.8356286
# 2018-11-01 00:00:01.333  1.5952808
# 2018-11-01 00:00:01.661  0.3295078
# 2018-11-01 00:00:01.988 -0.8204684
# 2018-11-01 00:00:02.316  0.4874291
# 2018-11-01 00:00:02.644  0.7383247
# 2018-11-01 00:00:02.972  0.5757814
# 2018-11-01 00:00:03.299 -0.3053884
```

To sum values within second points, you can use xts's `period.apply`, combined with finding the index of the last observation within each second using xts's `endpoints`:

```
ep <- endpoints(x, on = "seconds", k = 1)

xs <- period.apply(x, ep, sum)
```

"whole second" timestamps may not be desirable, which you can then fix using xts's `align.time`, which rounds to the end of the second (important to round to the end of the second to avoid generating look forward bias in your data)

```
xs
#                               [,1]
# 2018-11-01 00:00:00.677 -0.4428105
# 2018-11-01 00:00:01.988  0.2686916
# 2018-11-01 00:00:02.972  1.8015351
# 2018-11-01 00:00:03.299 -0.3053884

xs <- align.time(xs, n = 1)
xs
#                           [,1]
# 2018-11-01 00:00:01 -0.4428105
# 2018-11-01 00:00:02  0.2686916
# 2018-11-01 00:00:03  1.8015351
# 2018-11-01 00:00:04 -0.3053884
```